# JS each function inserts first value as "empty"

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatable

Some kind strange things happen. I am working with Datatable lib.
I have to collect numbers from a Nr. column. Every `td` in this column has class of `number` except `th` Nr. itself.

[image]

the code is simple:

```
    let array = [];
    table.on('row-reorder', function () {
        let i = 1;
        $('.number').each(function () {
            array[i] = $(this).text();
            i++;
        })
        console.log(array);
    })
```

I get an array with numbers, but the first value is empty:
[image]

Should I worry about this empty value when I post this array to php function and loop it to save numbers  in db?

Comment: You start your array from the `index` of 1. Try this `let i = 0;`

Comment: Thanks, I've spent more time to make this post, than to fix this thing... ((